# Azure AD Connect and server 2012 R2 essentials compatibility

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, migration, entra-id

The prerequisites for using Azure AD Connect don't list Server 2012 R2 Essentials, but they do list Server 2012 R2. Normally I understand pre-requisites just fine, but I'm not sure about the differences in this case between Server 2012 R2 and Server 2012 R2 Essentials.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47594

Would Server 2012 R2 Essentials be compatible with Azure AD Connect? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Server 2012 R2 Essentials is not compatible with AAD Connect. Essentials has a built in Azure directory sync however, which appears to do a similar job.